# What are the Azure SAS authorization parameters for copying to Azure Blobs?

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have an azcopy.exe command that I copied out of MS Azure Storage Explorer in order to use in a script.  The command works perfectly, but I want to understand the querystring parameters that are being used.

`?sv=2020-04-08&se=2021-10-29T15:07:01Z&sr=c&sp=rwl`

I understand that `sv` is signed version which I found in [Versioning for the Azure Storage services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services) and that section references the other parameters but I haven't been able to locate the actual docs.

I suspect that I'm close to it, but need some help.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes! That's what I was after. Thanks you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find information about SAS querystring parameters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas.

To specifically answer your question:

- **sv**: This is the storage REST API version.
- **se**: This is the date/time value in UTC when your SAS URL will expire.
- **sr**: This is the signed resource type. In your context, `sr=c` means that SAS token is acquired for a blob container.
- **sp**: These are the permissions included in your SAS token. Currently your signed permissions include `(r)ead`, `(w)rite` and `(l)ist` permissions.